# document.querySelector get class name containing parentheses

Tags: javascript, css

I am writing software that has to work with the dom of a third-party web-app that I don't control. Some of the class names have parameter, eg `class="view_box(200px)"`. I'm guessing these class names are Sass/Less mixins/arguments?

`document.querySelector` doesn't seem to like `.view_box(200px)` as a valid class selector, and simply querying `.view_box` doesn't return any of the elements that have the full string with argument as their class.

I tried escaping the parens as `\(` and `\)`. I even tried URL encoding them as `%28` and `%29`. I get the error `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.view_box(200px)' is not a valid selector.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass a literal backslash into the argument:

```
document.querySelector(".view_box\\(200px\\)")
```

Comment: And if there are more than a couple parentheses and the double-escaping seems too annoying, you can use `String.raw` instead

Comment: I just learned that there is a built-in function to escape these types of CSS reserved characters, which might help someone stumbling on this issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape