# Unable to include parentheses in hierarchical edge bundle text labels with D3 (v3)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I'm creating a hierarchical edge bundle chart using D3 (v3). I need my text labels to include parentheses in them (e.g. "name":"root.b.yes(1)"), however, this seems to stop the line highlighting from working when hovering over the label. According to the console, this renders the selector invalid. I've included code for a minimal example of just two labels that are connected to each other. If I remove the parentheses in my data.json file then on hover the lines highlight correctly, if the parentheses are included there's no line highlight. I'm not sure why parentheses aren't allowed and I haven't been able to find any help for this problem so far.

**console error message**

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '#node-yes(1)' is not a valid selector.
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">

path.arc {
  cursor: move;
  fill: #fff;
}

.node {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.node:hover {
  fill: #1f77b4;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #1f77b4;
  stroke-opacity: .4;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.link.source, .link.target {
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.node.target {
  fill: #d62728 !important;
}

.link.source {
  stroke: #d62728;
}

.node.source {
  fill: #2ca02c;
}

.link.target {
  stroke: #2ca02c;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>
    </h2>
    <div id="bundle"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;font-size:18px;">tension: <input style="position:relative;top:3px;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="85"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="packages.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var w = 740,
    h = 700,
    rx = w / 2,
    ry = h / 2,
    m0,
    rotate = 0
    pi = Math.PI;

var splines = [];

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([360, ry - 180])
    .sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.key, b.key); });

var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();

var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .interpolate("bundle")
    .tension(.85)
    .radius(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .angle(function(d) { return d.x / 180 * Math.PI; });

// Chrome 15 bug: <http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98951>
var div = d3.select("#bundle")
    .style("width", w + "px")
    .style("height", w + "px")
    .style("position", "absolute");

var svg = div.append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", w)
  .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + rx + "," + ry + ")");

svg.append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(ry - 180).innerRadius(0).startAngle(0).endAngle(2 * Math.PI))
    .on("mousedown", mousedown);

d3.json("data.json", function(classes) {
  var nodes = cluster.nodes(packages.root(classes)),
      links = packages.imports(nodes),
      splines = bundle(links);

  var path = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "link source-" + d.source.key + " target-" + d.target.key; })
      .attr("d", function(d, i) { return line(splines[i]); });

  var groupData = svg.selectAll("g.group")
    .data(nodes.filter(function(d) { return (d.key=='a' || d.key == 'b') && d.children; }))
  .enter().append("group")
    .attr("class", "group");
    
  var groupArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(ry - 177)
  .outerRadius(ry - 157)
  .startAngle(function(d) { return (findStartAngle(d.__data__.children)-2) * pi / 180;})
  .endAngle(function(d) { return (findEndAngle(d.__data__.children)+2) * pi / 180});
  
  svg.selectAll("g.arc")
  .data(groupData[0])
.enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", groupArc)
  .attr("class", "groupArc")
  .style("fill", "#1f77b4")
  .style("fill-opacity", 0.5);

  svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes.filter(function(n) { return !n.children; }))
    .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("id", function(d) { return "node-" + d.key; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
    .append("svg:text")
      .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? 25 : -25; })
      .attr("dy", ".31em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.key.replace(/_/g, ' '); })
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .on("mouseout", mouseout);

  d3.select("input[type=range]").on("change", function() {
    line.tension(this.value / 100);
    path.attr("d", function(d, i) { return line(splines[i]); });
  });
});

d3.select(window)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseup", mouseup);

function mouse(e) {
  return [e.pageX - rx, e.pageY - ry];
}

function mousedown() {
  m0 = mouse(d3.event);
  d3.event.preventDefault();
}

function mousemove() {
  if (m0) {
    var m1 = mouse(d3.event),
        dm = Math.atan2(cross(m0, m1), dot(m0, m1)) * 180 / Math.PI;
    div.style("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(0," + (ry - rx) + "px,0)rotate3d(0,0,0," + dm + "deg)translate3d(0," + (rx - ry) + "px,0)");
  }
}

function mouseup() {
  if (m0) {
    var m1 = mouse(d3.event),
        dm = Math.atan2(cross(m0, m1), dot(m0, m1)) * 180 / Math.PI;

    rotate += dm;
    if (rotate > 360) rotate -= 360;
    else if (rotate < 0) rotate += 360;
    m0 = null;

    div.style("-webkit-transform", "rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg)");

    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + rx + "," + ry + ")rotate(" + rotate + ")")
      .selectAll("g.node text")
        .attr("dx", function(d) { return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? 25 : -25; })
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)"; });
  }
}

function mouseover(d) {
  svg.selectAll("path.link.target-" + d.key)
      .classed("target", true)
      .each(updateNodes("source", true));

  svg.selectAll("path.link.source-" + d.key)
      .classed("source", true)
      .each(updateNodes("target", true));
}

function mouseout(d) {
  svg.selectAll("path.link.source-" + d.key)
      .classed("source", false)
      .each(updateNodes("target", false));

  svg.selectAll("path.link.target-" + d.key)
      .classed("target", false)
      .each(updateNodes("source", false));
}

function updateNodes(name, value) {
  return function(d) {
    if (value) this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
    svg.select("#node-" + d[name].key).classed(name, value);
  };
}

function cross(a, b) {
  return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0];
}

function dot(a, b) {
  return a[0] * b[0] + a[1] * b[1];
}

function findStartAngle(children) {
    var min = children[0].x;
    children.forEach(function(d) {
       if (d.x < min)
           min = d.x;
    });
    return min;
}

function findEndAngle(children) {
    var max = children[0].x;
    children.forEach(function(d) {
       if (d.x > max)
           max = d.x;
    });
    return max;
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**json**

```
[
    {"name":"root.a.no","imports":["root.b.yes(1)"]},
    {"name":"root.b.yes(1)","imports":[]}
]
```

**css**

```
body {
  font: 300 36px "Helvetica Neue";
  height: 640px;
  /*margin: 80px 160px 80px 160px;
  overflow: hidden;*/
  position: relative;
}

a:link, a:visited {
  color: rgb(202, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: rgb(245, 6, 6);
}

.invert {
  background: #1f1f1f;
  color: #dcdccc;
}

.invert h2, .invert h3 {
  color: #3eec3e;
}

.string, .regexp {
  color: #f39;
}

.keyword {
  color: #00c;
}

.comment {
  color: rgb(255, 28, 28);
  font-style: oblique;
}

.number {
  color: rgb(255, 21, 21);
}

.class, .special {
  color: #1181B8;
}

body > svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  left: -160px;
}
```

I know that future versions of D3 allow parentheses in the text labels but I need to specifically use version 3.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two things that I think could work:

1. Try adding [escape backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53893708/16384621) for the query string
2. If after that, d3v3 still does not support this directly, I believe that the workaround would be to pass to select the [HTML node instead of the selector string](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#select). So you could do something like:

   ```
    const node = document.querySelector('#node-yes(1)')
    d3.select(node).classed(...)
   ```

And then again, if it doesn't work, try escaping the parenthesis when selecting:
(edit)

```
  const parsedKey = d[name].key.replace("(", "\\(").replace(")", "\\)")
  svg.select("#node-" + parsedKey).classed(name, value)
```

(update) This would have to be done every time a node is selected

. I believe that if none of these two options work, then you would need to bump up  the version of d3

Comment: Thanks for your help. Escaping the backlashes (with two backslashes) worked in that the lines now highlight correctly but the label now appears on the page with one backlash either side. Do you know why? I've tried using one backslash either side but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Beatdown are you adding the backslashes to the json? Or when you query?

Comment: I was adding them to the json, is this incorrect? I'm struggling to see where I can add them anywhere else (new to JS).

Comment: I wouldn't say it's incorrect, but maybe you could try adding them before selection with a replace, i'll update my answer

Comment: I tried that and I'm getting this error: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': 'path.link.source-yes(1)' is not a valid selector.

Comment: i think you're missing the `"#node-" + ` part

Comment: No, here's my function: 

function updateNodes(name, value) {
  return function(d) {
    if (value) this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
    const parsedKey = d[name].key.replace("(", "\\(").replace(")", "\\)")
    svg.select("#node-" + parsedKey).classed(name, value);
  };
}

Comment: Did you try with two backslashes? Considering that's how the selection worked for you before, It should be like that here as well

Comment: The backslashes are in the query part and not in the json file. If I add them to the json file they are merely displayed (incorrectly). Currently with your query solution, the display is correct i.e. yes(1), but there's no highlight due to: 'path.link.target-yes(1)' is not a valid selector.

Comment: Yes, but when you added them to the json, you said that it worked correctly when using two backslashes (i.e. `\\(` and `\\)`). However, in the code you sent above you're just using one backslash per parenthesis

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I'm using two backslashes. In the code above, I think stackoverflow changed it to one (not sure why). I'm confused as to how it's still not a valid constructor despite that it displays correctly on the label.

Comment: In my 'updateNodes' function it seems that I can change #node- to anything with no change in error message. I wonder if I need to add this parsedKey solution elsewhere in the code too? other than inside the updateNodes function? Since 'mouseover' is the issue, should I change something in the 'mouseover' function? function mouseover(d) {
  svg.selectAll("path.link.target-" + d.key)..

Comment: Oh yes, definitely. You should do so every time that you select a node.